# Visual Studio 2019 Stopped Pushing to Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have VS Community 2019 and everything was working fine with my Git repo on Azure DevOps.  However VS updated this morning and now for some reason it won't push to Git.  It seems like that must be the issue because that's the only thing that changed since the last time I pushed.  Now when I try to push my commits I get this:

```
> Pushing develop Error encountered while pushing to the remote
> repository: Git failed with a fatal error. unable to access
> '<<my repo>>':
> error setting certificate verify locations:   CAfile: c:/program files
> (x86)/microsoft visual
> studio/2019/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team
> explorer/Git/mingw32/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none Pushing to
> <<my repo>>
```

The really odd part is if I just do a git bash at the repo directory and use `git push` it works...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the path is still valid (still exist) after VS update:

```
dir "c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

If it does, search for another `curl-ca-bundle.crt` under "`c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/`" in case the update created a new one.

Check also your `git config -l --show-origin` includes only one entry

```
http.sslcainfo=/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: So sorry for the late response.  I posted then had to put out a fire then holidays... Anyway THANK YOU!  Need to do some more experimenting to make sure it's fully fixed, but http.sslcainfo was not set at all.  I set that and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

If the file **`curl-ca-bundle.crt`** doesn't exist in:

```
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

Try copying the CRT file from your local git installation.

Use command prompt to run `git config -l --show-origin`. Look for the entry `http.sslcainfo=/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. Copy the file `ca-bundle.crt` into the visual studio directory `../team explorer/Git/mingw32/bin/` and rename it to `curl-ca-bundle.crt`.

Restart Visual Studio and try pushing again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in Visual Studio 2022, but Git started functioning normally, after I re-reinstalled Git in my machine (leaving link below). For me, the path displayed in error did not exist and when I opened the path C:/Program Files/Git, it was empty. This was happening after I uninstalled Git in my machine, so that prompted me to re-install it.

Link for git download: https://git-scm.com/download/win

Answer (score 0):

In all of these cases, the recommendation is to upgrade the Git credential Manager for Windows.

https://jessehouwing.net/configure-visual-studio-to-use-a-different-git-credential-manager-for-windows/

Comment: I did also follow this and updated GCMW and pointed Git to use that one so it's possible that this was part of the solution.  However after ONLY doing that it was still failing and when I set the SSL CA as above it started working.  Upvoting for the help but giving answer to VonC.  Thank you!

Comment: For someone who does not want to upgrade, just goto Credential Manager and memove all current accounts that relate to Git/Azure Devops

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating my Visual Studio 2019. It was unable to find filepath: c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/bin/ca-bundle.crt

Search for **ca-bundle.crt** in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019**

copy ca-bundle.crt and paste it in the directory where it is looking for it. If the directory does not exist, create **c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/bin** and paste the certificate into it.