# How do i fix github on visual studio?

Tags: github, ssl, repository, visual-studio-2022, fatal-error

I have had this error coming up every time I try cloning a repository from Git hub to Visual studio.

[image]

If someone knows how to fix this issue could you please provide a step by step process of what to do and maybe explain what's going on too during each step.

- I've tried contacting customer support from GitHub directly and got nothing.
- I've tried uninstalling & reinstalling git bash and visual studio 2022 it did not work.
- I've tried using chat gpt to get a solution to issue.
- I've also tried resigning into my GitHub account and it didn't work.

Edit:
i looked in the folder for the .crt file but there was nothing in the folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agS2X.png)
i'm not sure if this is the correct place to look.

i also did checked if there was only one entry in git and there was so i don't know what else to do or how to do it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inymq.png)

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297224/visual-studio-2019-stopped-pushing-to-git

Comment: Yeah i did see this, ill try doing this again and update my post if it does or doesn’t exist.

Comment: I just updated the post to include what i did.